# What is the Python equivalent of R's .Last.value?

Tags: python, r

In R, I can do:

```
> 3 + 1 + 4 + 1 + 5 + 9
[1] 23
> 1 + .Last.value
[1] 24
```

What is the Python equivalent of `.Last.value`?

Comment: in an interactive python shell: `_`. in a `jupyter` shell you can also access previous outputs by their  number (`5` in this example): `_5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using *interactive interpreter* it is `_` that is

```
>>> 3 + 1 + 4 + 1 + 5 + 9
23
>>> 1 + _
24
```

This behavior is described in [docs Reserved classes of identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers) as follows

> Separately, the interactive interpreter makes the result of the last
> evaluation available in the variable `_`.